# Android. Method getduration() of MediaPlayer returns wrong value

Tags: android

I have the following issue with getduration() method of android MediaPlayer. For example with the following file(the real duration of the file is 5747000 ms) :

[File to test it](http://sdmedia.playser.cadenaser.com/Podcast/2015/7/29/000WB0820620150729015306.mp3)

After MediaPlayer is prepared, I'm printing in log cat current position and getduration value in the following code :

```
Log.d("Podcast", "getDuration:"+mediaPlayer.getDuration());
Log.d("Podcast","getCurrentPosition:"+mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition());
```

In log cat I can see the following  :

```
D/Podcast﹕ getDuration:2885642
D/Podcast﹕ getCurrentPosition:3288059
```

I found another post with information about that but I have not found a solution. 
[Similar issue found on stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145652/mediaplayer-getduration-returning-wrong-duration)

How is it possible? Can anyone help me on this?

Thanks. Regards.

Comment: I think your case is also the same with that [SO Q&A](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11145652/mediaplayer-getduration-returning-wrong-duration). And [Artem Svystun's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13862261/3501958) may be true. It's not a problem of android but a problem of some mp3 files which have illegal meta information. Your testing mp3 file is also indicated as 2884s with my Ubuntu's file information.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Do you know if there is any work around for that? For example VLC player don't show the duration of the file but at least create a seekbar with the proper duration and you can seek to ,....

Comment: [Some tools](http://askubuntu.com/questions/248811/how-can-i-fix-incorrect-mp3-duration) could fix wrong headers of mp3 files.

Comment: Thanks, but the files are not generated by me . It's like a podcast manager.  Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

According to this thread: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2559 
The mp3 file should be on 44,100 Hz. Otherwise, the MediaPlayer will scale the time by the ratio of the MP3's actual sample rate to 44,100 Hz.

Comment: In this thread the
media player's getCurrentPosition() returns a false value. In my case the wrong value is returned by getduration() method because when getCurrentPosition() is > getduration() the audio continues playing.

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert it into miliseconds..

```
 public String milliSecondsToTimer(long milliseconds) {
        String finalTimerString = "";
        String secondsString = "";
        String mp3Minutes = "";
        // Convert total duration into time

        int minutes = (int) (milliseconds % (1000 * 60 * 60)) / (1000 * 60);
        int seconds = (int) ((milliseconds % (1000 * 60 * 60)) % (1000 * 60) / 1000);

        // Prepending 0 to seconds if it is one digit
        if (seconds < 10) {
            secondsString = "0" + seconds;
        } else {
            secondsString = "" + seconds;
        }
// menor que 10
        if (minutes < 10) {
            mp3Minutes = "0" + minutes;
        } else {
            mp3Minutes = "" + minutes;
        }
        finalTimerString = finalTimerString + mp3Minutes + ":" + secondsString;
        // return timer string
        return finalTimerString;
    }
```

Then,

```
 private Runnable mUpdateTimeTask = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            if (mediaPlayer != null && isPlaying) {
                long totalDuration = mediaPlayer.getDuration();
                long currentDuration = mediaPlayer.getCurrentPosition();
                musicSongDurationStart.setText("" + utils.milliSecondsToTimer(currentDuration) + "/" + utils.milliSecondsToTimer(totalDuration));
            }
            if (!isPause) {
                musicSongDurationStart.postDelayed(mUpdateTimeTask, 100);
            }

            // Running this thread after 100 milliseconds
        }
    };
```

I hope it will help you.